# Best approach, htaccess file fallback in another folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, fallback

I'm looking to centralise the resources of a number of small websites in one hosting account. 
The main resources for each site will be in one core folder, however each site should be able to overide the core if needed.

So I'm trying to get htaccess redirection to first look in the local folder for requested files, then fall back to the resources folder if the file is not present.... I'm tying myself in knots!

I know how to do basic redirects and have been reading through various tuts, but think I'm getting the syntax wrong. I was also looking at the fallbackresource directive, but I don't think this is meant for this scenario.

I tried something along these lines but it didn't seem to work, and obviously it is only aimed at the img folder - I'm guessing I need some wildcards in there to cover all bases:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^img/(.*) http://domain.com/resources/img/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated! This is a very basic illustration of my intended structure:

```
    .htaccess
    |
    |-/Resources
       |-/img
          |-img1.jpg 
       |-/styles
          |-style.css
       |-/cms
          |-core.php
    |
    |-/Site1
       |-index.php
       |-page2.php
       |-/img
       |-/styles
       |-/cms
    |
    |-/Site2
       |-index.php
       |-page2.php
       |-/img
       |-/styles
          |-style.css [local override file]
       |-/cms
```